# References for Hilbert schemes over non-Archimedean valuation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hilbert-schemes, hilbert-function

Can you suggest me some suitable references to learn the theory of Hilbert polynomials (or related Hilbert schemes) in the non-Archimedean setting?

Thanks.

Comment: The Hilbert scheme and Hibert polynomial make sense over any field. What in particular do you want to know about the case of non-archimedean fields? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: By 'the non-archimedean setting', do you mean some category of rigid or adic spaces? Typically, Hilbert polynomials are attached to an ample line bundle on a proper space, making the space projective (hence algebraic). So I think the analytic theory should not differ from the algebraic one.